# Mule MEL to do substring on a flow variable

Tags: mule, mule-el

I have a variable my_variable with value as a dynamic URL like --

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

I want to do a substring on this dynamic URL to find the string after last "/" i.e. in case above mentioned URL, I want to get the substring "ask"

How can I use MEL to do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the string functions which are availalbe from the java.lang package.

```
#[flowVars['my_variable'].substring(flowVars['my_variable'].lastIndexOf('/'))]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JDK classes in MEL, in fact these packages are auto imported (http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Reference):

- java.lang.*
- java.io.*
- java.net.*
- java.util.*
- java.math.BigDecimal
- java.math.BigInteger
- javax.activation.DataHandler
- javax.activation.MimeType
- java.util.regex.Pattern
- org.mule.api.transformer.DataType
- org.mule.transformer.types.DataTypeFactory

This flow receives requests on port 8081 and return the last part of the path:

```
<flow name="testedbFlow3">
    <http:inbound-endpoint host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    <expression-transformer expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.request'].split(&quot;^.*/&quot;)[1]]"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic Java `String` methods such as `substring()` and `lastIndexOf()` on the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
#[flowVars['my_variable'].substring(flowVars['my_variable'].lastIndexOf('/'))]
```

which is simpler one

Comment: This is the same as @user1760178's answer, except yours is missing the necessary pound sign.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.